# how do I import the data of a csv file per category and sum it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to coding and am having some problems making my code work. What I have is three columns, which have the same category. one column is a string value, ie children, and the other two discuss grams and micrograms.  I want to get a sum of the combined total micrograms and grams in the specified category (in this example that is children) but instead, my code is only returning either a list of the values, or error codes. What do I need to fix?

| Category | Grams | Micrograms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Children | 2 | 99,99 |
| Children | 1 | 4 |

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import pandas as pd
filename = '/Users/Desktop/20220503_python_input_template.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename,delimiter=';',decimal=',',na_values=-9999.99)

df = df[df['mass per item (g)'].notna()]


cat = df["Category"]
subcat = df["Sub-category"]
m_p = df["mass per item (g)"]
m_mp = df["mass micro per item (g)"]
m_fe = df["Frequency as factor"]

print("Do You have any children?\n1) No\n2) Yes- 1\n3) Yes-2\n4) Yes-3")#

val1 = int(input("Enter value: "))

info = df.loc[cat.str.contains("Children", case=False)]

idx=df.index[cat=='Children'].tolist() 
total+= m_p.iloc[idx] + mm_p.iloc[idx] 

print(total)

else:
print("Invalid")
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you would like the data to look like?

Comment: That code isn't going to run, since you have an `else:` without an `if`, and the line after the else is not indented. Please take the time to make sure the code here looks the same as on your computer.

Comment: Second issue, can you share both what output you are getting, and what output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need sum of grams and micrograms per category:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = '/Users/Desktop/20220503_python_input_template.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename,delimiter=';',decimal=',',na_values=-9999.99)
df.groupby(by='Category').sum()
```

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.